# Disable ag-grid when showing loading- or any overlay

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

When showing the loading overlay (or any other overlay) by using the api call

`gridOptions.api.showLoadingOverlay()`

in ag-grid, the rows and all grid-functions (buttons, context-menu, etc.) below the overlay are still selectable/usable.

Is there any way that I can prevent that from happening? Are there any plans to change this behaviour in a future release?

Answer (score 5):

Add this CSS rule:

```
.ag-bl-overlay {
    pointer-events: auto;
}
```

For some reason the default CSS for this selector is:

```
.ag-bl-overlay {
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;

    pointer-events: none;

    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

With **pointer-events** being set to **none** which is the source of all of this grief and misery!

Comment: As of `ag-grid-react` version `22.1.1` the class is now `ag-overlay`. (Could have changed in an earlier version)

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same issue and didn't find any solution to disable the grid.
so I have set the rowData to empty array before loadingOverlay so that user doesn't have the option to modify the old data while new data is being load.

```
gridOptions.api.setRowData([]);
gridOptions.api.showLoadingOverlay();
```

Answer (score 0):

For serverside ag grid you can do the following

```
gridOptions.api.purgeServerSideCache([],0)
gridOptions.api.showLoadingOverlay();
```